# Does a 64 bit runtime run faster than a 32 bit?

Tags: operating-system, runtime

Does a 64 bit run-time run faster than a 32 bit? Was our childhood a lie?

**Backstory:**
A runtime I really like has been updated to 64 bit. As a programmer, the only thing I could think of was that meant that you could create larger numbers and access more memory.

But growing up the newest consoles went from 8 bit, to 16 bit, then 32 bit and you won't guess what's next, 64 bit. So everyone knew 16 bit was better in every way, including speed, than 8 bit.

So when my favorite runtime says it's upgraded to 64 bit does it mean it's faster than the 32 bit? It's upgraded for Mac OS X and will be upgraded to 64 bit for Windows as well.

Also, it looks like [Firefox](http://www.engadget.com/2015/12/15/firefox-64-bit-windows/) just went 64 bit.

Comment: All other things equal, 64-bit code should theoretically run somewhat _slower_ than 32-bit code simply because more bits of code and data need to be processed to accomplish the same result. 64-bit code's main advantage is access to a much larger address space.

Comment: OK I've updated the original post with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processor word size (32 or 64) is somewhat independent of the the speed. Generally 64-bit processors are newer than those supporting only 32-bits, so they are inherently faster. However, manipulating more data, larger addresses is inherently slower than manipulating smaller data (shorter addresses).

Let's say that you have a library that does image processing (e.g., read/write JPEG files) in which you need to do 64-bit scaled integers (at 32-bits, you get serious rounding errors in JPEG). The 64-bit processor can add a 64-bit scale integer in one instruction. A 32-bit processor would take 3 or more instructions to do the same (inherently slower).

64 bits means access to more memory (if you use a CAD program you know what that means); not more speed. But, because 64-bit processors tend to be newer and faster, you generally get more speed; but not because of 64-bits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer from a low level developer, x64 can be very optimized because it has 8 additional 128 bit Multimedia XMM Registers, All 32 Bit registers are extended to 64 Bit, and an additional 8 General Purpose registers R8-R15. This all can be used to minimize memory access, computations, and copying large buffers which are the **main** slowdown for a CPU, programs in x64 already know there is SSE & SSE2 So they can benefit from these extensions without checking for them or creating double the functions. (there is also 256Bit AVX/512Bit AVX512).

The main thing about why they are called 64 bit is because these processors provide a 64 Bit Flat Address space when you can use 48 Bit Paging (256 TB) or (if supported) 57 Bit Paging (2^57 Bytes).